# sending ajax request on two pages?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am trying to send ajax post request on two php pages which are 1. properties.php and 2. profile.php the code i am trying it sends ajax request on properties.php so how i can send the  same post request on profile.php below is my code

index.php

```
<div id="div-second-dropdown"></div>
<div id="div-third-dropdown"></div>
```

ajax.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    sendAjax();
});
function sendAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'properties.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'account-id=' + $('#account-dropdown').val(),
        success: function (html) {
            $('#div-second-dropdown').html(html);
                        $.ajax(
    {
        url: 'analytics.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'account-id=' + $('#account-dropdown').val(),
        success: function (html) {
            $('#div-third-dropdown').html(html);


        }
    }
);
        }
    });
}
```

properties.php

```
<?php 

echo $_POST['accountid'];
?>
```

it display the post value on index.php in #div-second-dropdown.

profile.php

```
<?php 

    echo $_POST['accountid'];
    ?>
```

it don't display the post value on index.php in #div-third-dropdown

Comment: Huh? If you want to send another request to a different file, just replace `url: 'properties.php'`. Am I missing something?

Comment: you could use any kind of loop client side or send request to a proxy php script which then will handle it for both scripts server side

Comment: The question is titled `sending ON two pages`. From the question I take it should be named `sending TO two pages`. Correct?

Comment: actually i have 3 dropdowns 2nd dropdown is depended on first one and third dropdown in depended on first and second dropdown. as i need to do some calculations so i am creating these dropdowns on different pages and displaying them on index.php in divs

Comment: This seems you want consecutive ajax requests: selecting value in 1stdropdown sets new values for 2nd, which should reset the 3rdwith new values from 1st and 2nd. But you have the 2nd value only once the 2nd is loaded, and this means you have to place the request for the 3rd into success callback of the 2nd.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of jquery promise and playing around to execute the 2nd call if the first is successful.

```
function sendAjax(dest)
{
    return $.ajax({
        url: dest + '.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'account-id=' + $('#account-dropdown').val(),
        success: function (html) {
            $('#div-second-dropdown').html(html);
        },
        error: function(s)
        {
            return s;
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    sendAjax('properties').then( function(){ sendAjax('profile')} );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    sendAjax();

});


function sendAjax() 
{

    $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'properties.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'account-id=' + $('#account-dropdown').val(),
            success: function (html) {
                $('#div-second-dropdown').html(html);
$.ajax(
    {
        url: 'profile.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {'account-id': $('#account-dropdown').val(),
               'profile-id': $('#profile-dropdown').val()},
        success: function (html) {
            $('#div-third-dropdown').html(html);
        }
    }
);
            }
        }
    );    

}
```

The first A in ajax stands for asyncronous, so the second request is made before the first one finishes. There might be session locking problem.

Comment: Or he can add param to sendAjax function i.e. sendAjax(url) and set url as url for ajax then just call that function any number of times needed.

Comment: Also to deal with async "problem" he can call second on callback complete of the first.

Comment: Echo? The success callback does the same thing in my posted code (as I don't know what you want to do), so they are competing agains each other, and the later to finish wins.

Answer (score -1):

Try calling the second page ajax call in the success callback of first ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   sendAjax();
});

function sendAjax(myUrl) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'properties.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'account-id=' + $('#account-dropdown').val(),
        success: function (html) {
            $('#div-second-dropdown').html(html);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'profile.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: 'account-id=' + $('#account-dropdown').val(),
                success: function (html) {
                    $('#div-second-dropdown').html(html);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I hate these “try this” answers that just throw some code out there without any explanation … Please put a bit of effort into answers so people can actually take something from it - other than copying code and on their next, similar problem ask again.

Comment: @Kissaki same here....was in the middle of updating when u pointed it out..any waz thnks :)

Comment: @UmarKhan ok lets check if u are able to ajax call correctly.Simply use my code put 2 alerts in both ajax calls success callback and see if u get them.If not plz update your newly modified code....and i'll if i can help

Comment: @iJay i have updated my question the first ajax call works fine as it display the value in div but second ajax call don't display the value in second div in index.php

Comment: @UmarKhan ok..i get dat it doesn't display a value in but are u getting a success response in the second ajax call??

Comment: @iJay pardon me i am really new to ajax... i tried alter to check the response but it didn't alter.

Comment: in the success simply put an alert(html) and tell me what u got.